# mosfet capacitance charging question

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, level-shifting, level-translation

Can someone please explain to me why the output of this level-shifting circuit starts charging from around 2.8V to 5V, and NOT from 3.3V to 5V.

At the time where the output is at 5V there is a 3.3V potential at the source and gate terminal.

So i thought that the drain-source capacitance and the gate-drain capacitance would ramp up from 3.3V to 5V.

below is the circuit diagram and oscilloscope pictures. I get the exact same results when simulating the circuit, so i am definitely missing something. 
[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

After studying my simulation a bit more:

[image]

This is what it looks like when i zoom. The voltage is initially 3.3V. Could this be due to reverse recovery??? so that the body diode conducts in the reverse condition for a short period of time. Could that be why the source voltage goes to 2.7V because of a diode drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simplified capacitor MOSFET model... In this model, all switches switch at the same time, so when the input switches the short across C3 is removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRRwP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When it initially switches the gate jumps up to 6.6V and the drain to 3.3V. The gate charge quickly drops down to zero and C2 discharges into C3 (Cds) creating a negative Vds voltage. With equal capacitances, and the diode disconnected, the output would reach half 3.3V. Thereafter the capacitors are charged though R1.

[image]

With the diode connected across C3, it prevents the output dropping under Vf below the input voltage. Which is what you are witnessing.

[image]

Of course the real model is more complicated than that and includes inductances, but for the scope of your question at hand, this model is sufficient.

As for the capacitance. If you look at your scope trace you will see that the charge is almost linear as it first rises. This is because the capacitance falls as Vds increases.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on FET diode and Vgs.

- dV/dt = Ic/Coss
- Icoss= (5V-Vds)/ R when Vgs
- initially when FET is turned off, the body diode causes Vds =Vgs-Vf

When Vgs goes to 3.3 and Vds goes to 3V the rest is probe capacitance ?? pF +Coss and R pullup

Here your rise time is 2 us thus C=t/R=2us/10k=200pF
This is consistent with fig 5 on your missing data sheet. For Coss vs. Vds

This explains your results.

Remember this.

- low RdsOn FETs will have high Coss and Coss(Vds)*RdsOn(Vgs) = FoM a figure of merit that changes with FET design and Vgs max

Comment: De nada, from Sevilla Spain

Comment: Tony can you explain why 200pF seems to give me the correct rise time, when it should be closer to 600pF according to the datasheet?

Comment: But why is that? when Vgate and Vsource is at 3.3V, Vdrain is at 5V. Why are there a voltage drop of 0.6-0.7 between the gate and source when Vgs = 0V ???

Comment: @MatBE never mind... I got that wrong..

Comment: I have just updated my post with a new simulation screenshot. Would you take a look at it and tell me if my theory could be right?

Comment: @MatBE It is a great deal more complicated than the simple model here. If you look at your initial trace, note the charge grows almost linearly initially, that will have to do with the capacitance changing as Vds grows. Also, since it is with a real part on the scope the actual capacitance values may be less than the max in the spec.

Comment: @MatBE As for the simulation plot. You have to remember the gate drain/gate source is also charged up to 3.3V initially. That needs discharged too. It's a complicated model.

Comment: It only needs discharged when the output is at 0V. The problem is when the output ramps up to 5V. I know that the drain/source capacitance needs charging along with the gate/drain capacitance. I just don't understand it ramps up from 2.7V. 
I haven't noticed the linearly increase initially. That looks like a changing capacitance for sure, thanks!

Comment: BTW you don't see that initial spike it on the scope because you don't have zero time rise time on whatever is driving it.

Comment: Makes sense, i forgot about that oops. But could the body-diode lower the source voltage of about 0.7V when it is immediately switched to reverse condition?

Comment: @MatBE there is a wide tolerance on Coss but unspecified

Comment: Yes @MatBE Diode ESR is low so immediate jump to 2.7 . Silicon diode 0.6